# Get pointer to first char that differs between two C strings

Tags: c, string

Is there a stardard C function that will compare two C strings, and return a pointer to the first character that is different, and NULL if the strings are equal?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    const char *p, *s1 = "foobar", *s2 = "foobaz";

    p = strdiffchr(s1, s2);
    if (!p)
        puts("the strings are equal");
    else
        printf("s1 has %c, where s2 has %c\n", *p, s2[p - s1]);

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** I have chosen the following solution:

```
char *strdiffchr(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    while (*s1 && *s1 == *s2) {
        s1++;
        s2++;
    }
    return (*s1 == *s2) ? NULL : (char *)s1;
}
```

Comment: The function wouldn't return a pointer, but a character index.

Comment: I can't find `strdiffchr` in C's reference

Comment: I guess that's what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not think that there is such a function. Coding it up can be done in a single `for` loop, though:

```
const char *p1, *p2, *s1 = "foobar", *s2 = "foobaz";
for (p1 = s1, p2 = s2 ; *p1 && *p1 == *p2 ; p1++, p2++)
    ; // Loop body is empty, because everything is done in the header.
const char *p = *p1 || *p2 ? p1 : NULL;
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/g0epf9)

Comment: Minor: could simplify `*p1 && *p1 == *p2`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I knew it could easily be done, but I thought there might be a standard function for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

```
int findIndexOfMismatch(const char *a, const char *b) {
    int i = 0;
    while (a[i] == b[i] && a[i])
       i++;
    return a[i] || b[i] ? i : -1;
}
```

This returns `-1` if the two strings match. This returns an index rather than a pointer; you could instead return a pointer: for example:

```
    return a[i] || b[i] ? a + i : 0; // NB: pointer to a, not b, or null if equal
```

Comment: Assuming the string are NULL-delimited, you should also to a strlen() comparison of both strings for safety.

Comment: @Dogbert Does not `...&& a[i])` take care of `strlen()` issues?